# Find a harmonic function $u$ when $u(e^{i\theta})=0$ for $0<\theta<\pi$ and $1$ for $\pi<\theta<2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a real-valued function $u$ which is harmonic in $\{z:|z|<1\}$ and
>   $$u(e^{i\theta})=
> \begin{cases}
> 1, & 0<\theta<\pi \\
> 0, & \pi<\theta<2\pi
> \end{cases}
> $$

I found a function like
$$u(z)=\Re\left( \dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan(-iz)+\dfrac{1}{2} \right)$$
but cannot find the real part form explicitly.

My textbook suggest a solution like 
$$u(re^{i\theta})=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan\dfrac{1-r^2}{-2r\sin\theta}$$
and maybe this form will be similar with the real part of my solution.

How can I get the explicit form like that?

Comment: Do you know the poisson integral formula?

Comment: @zokomoko Thanks for your critical hint!